# How to use WinCap 3.1 dll in Windows10

Tags: labview

I am trying to run an old LabView v8.2 program which used WinCap 3.1 but there seems not to be any replacement for the WinCap dll to run on my Windows10.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What does WinCap do? Perhaps there are alternatives?

Comment: https://www.winpcap.org/install/ says "The WinPcap project has ceased development and WinPcap and WinDump are no longer maintained. WE RECOMMEND USING Npcap INSTEAD."  That library is at https://npcap.com/ and there is also a Windows 10 version made by someone else at https://www.win10pcap.org/

Comment: @JerryJeremiah thanks, i did found the same info and links some days after. Thanks a lot anyway!